# Displaying JSON data with Vue3

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs3

This is weird, but it is the first time I have dealt with JSON in Vue3, and it doesn't seem to be reacting as I expected.

I have some JSON in a Vue DataObject called dataObject

```
data() {
  return {
    dataObject: {}
  }
},
```

My JSON data looks, something, like this,

```
{
  "myDataList": [
    {
      "list_item_1_1": "1234",
      "list_item_1_2": "2023-09-21T09:06:13.000Z",
      ...
      "list_item_1_6": [
        {
          "inline_list_item_1_6_1": "ABCD",
          ...
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "list_item_2_1": "EFGH",
      "list_item_2_2": "5678",
      "list_item_2_3": "IJKL",
      ...
      "list_item_2_8": {
        "list_item_2_8_1": "OK",
        "list_item_2_8_2": "MAYBE",
        "list_item_2_8_3": "9011"
      },
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Now for some reason I can't reach into the data and pull out, for example, `list_item_2_8`. As this is Vue I am using `<p>Data Value: {{this.dataObject.1.list_item_2_8}</p>`, however this gives me an `Unexpected token` error in the console. When I run this through a JSON tool, this configuration of JSON is valid...

StackOverflow, Google, JSONFormatter.org and JSONQueryTool.com

Could someone point me in the right direction please? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to what you printed, it should be `this.dataObject.myDataList[1].list_item_2_8`. You might want to read up on what "JSON data" means, misusing the term makes people giddy.

Comment: Yeah, Vue hates that as well... `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list_item_2_8')`. My apologise, if JSON data is an incorrect term, what should I use instead, as from what I understand, JSON response would also be wrong :(

Comment: @Takuhii you're dealing with an object that has a nested array of objects. So what Moritz is saying is that you need to brush up on how to access properties within an object. This isn't entirely relevant and kind of old but I recommend you watch fun fun functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhbhD1HR5vk&list=PL0zVEGEvSaeHBZFy6Q8731rcwk0Gtuxub

Comment: I am afraid I am a little lost here...